# If two Hamiltonians produce the same evolution up to a phase, are they equivalent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, hamiltonian, quantum-computer, quantum-states

Consider two Hamiltonian operators $H_1, H_2$ and the evolution of some fixed single-qubit state $|\psi\rangle$ and yielding:
$$
\exp(i H_1t)|\psi\rangle = |\phi\rangle \\
\exp(i H_2t)|\psi \rangle = e^{i\theta}|\phi \rangle
$$
So the evolved state picks up a global phase after the time evolution of $H_2$.

**Questions**:

1. Do we consider $H_1$ **equivalent** to $H_2$ given that the probability amplitudes of the output states are equal? This is true because:
   $$||\phi\rangle|^2 = |e^{i\theta}|\phi \rangle|^2$$
   In this case, I would say that any Hamiltonians whose output states differ by global phases are experimentally equivalent.
2. If instead of a single qubit we have $n$ qubits do the above hold true? By that I mean, can the Hamiltonian evolution yield global phases as above or there exist more generic such transformations?

Comment: Is $|\psi\rangle$ a specific qubit state or an arbitrary state?

Comment: A fixed qubit state.

Comment: I have to assume that you mean this to be the case for a fixed $t \neq 0$, assuming $\theta$ is time independent?

Comment: Of course. This is the case I am considering.

Comment: even if you require equality on all input states, that is, you require equality of the operators themselves, $e^{iH_1}=e^{iH_2}$, you can have (generally infinitely) many different solutions. Consider for example $H_1=2\pi I$ and $H_2=2\pi X$ with $X$ Pauli matrix. These satisfy $e^{iH_1}=e^{iH_2}$, and thus in particular your requirement with $\theta=0$.

Comment: Why $\exp(iH_1)=\exp(iH_2)$ here? Or is the equal sign supposed to mean equivalent in the evolution of the state?

Comment: @Marion I don't understand the question. Are you asking why I didn't put the $t$? You can add a factor $t$ in the exponentials if you want, it doesn't really make a difference (as long as it's fixed of course, which seems to be what you are asking about). The equal sign means just identity of the operators

Comment: I don't see directly why the operators are identified. $H_1$ is different to $H_2$. Is the action of these operators on a given state identified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes such Hamiltonians are considered equivalent. And, two different hamiltonians which only produce a global phase difference must differ by a real constant $H_2 = H_1 + C$.

You can have the same for $n$ qubits: a global - meaning, spin-independent - phase difference in the Hamiltonian can be neglected.

I believe that there are not generalizations for multiple qubits, either: it seems to me that a global phase change is the most general equivalent Hamiltonian of the kind you are looking at. If $H$ added a phase to each qubit in a product state, like

$$H_2 = (\theta_1\mathbb{I} \otimes \theta_2\mathbb{I} \otimes ...) +H_1$$

then these phases would add to just one global phase $e^{-it(\theta_1 + \theta_2 + ...)}$.

And if the modification $H_1 \to H_2$ instead added different phases to different terms in a superposition, the state would no longer be equivalent to the original state.

EDIT: Proof that the Hamiltonians must differ by a constant:

Defining our variables:
$$U_1(t) = e^{-itH_1}  \,\,\,\,\,\,\, U_1(t) = e^{-itH_2}$$

And by the premise, $U_2(t) |\psi \rangle = e^{-it \theta} U_1(t) |\psi \rangle $ for all times $t$ and all states $|\psi \rangle$. **Note:** You do need a $t$ here, or else you need to pick a fixed time. Then

$$e^{itH_2} |\psi \rangle = e^{i t \theta} e^{itH_1} |\psi \rangle $$

$$e^{itH_2} |\psi \rangle = e^{it(H_1+ \theta)} |\psi \rangle $$

Since this must be true for all states $|\psi \rangle$, the only possibility is if the operators are equal

$$e^{itH_2}=e^{it(H_1+ \theta)}$$

This implies that the Hamiltonians must differ only by a constant $\theta$.

Comment: But $H_1$ and $H_2$ could, in principle evolve a state $|\psi^\prime\rangle$ differently, no?! For example if it is an eigenstate of $H_1$ but not an eigenstate of $H_2$...

Comment: Not the $H_1$ and $H_2$ which differ just by a real constant (sorry I was missing a plus sign, fixed). Also, I just saw the clarification in the comments. Maybe I misinterpreted your question. Do you want $H$ to depend on the state $|\phi\rangle$? Or are you asking in general, regardless of which $|\phi \rangle$ we pick?

Comment: No, $H$ does not depend on the state $|\phi\rangle$. I don't see what exactly this even means. We pick an initial state, say the north pole in the Bloch sphere and assume that the evolution by $H_1$ takes the north pole to a point in the equator $q_1$. Assume that $H_2$ does the same but to another point in the equator $q_2$. Since, obviously, $p_2 = g p_1 $ for some $g \in U(1)$, does this mean $H_1,H_2$ are equivalent since the probabilities match?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your comment, since two points on the equator of the Bloch sphere are not only different by a global phase, and they don't give the same probabilities. Global phases don't even show up on the Bloch sphere, so if you had $|\phi \rangle$ vs $e^{i\theta}|\phi \rangle$, they would be represented by the same point on the Bloch sphere.

Comment: I apologize. Yes, you are right. Please disregard my comment since I agree with the response on it. Definitely, the phase symmetry is not apparent on the Bloch sphere (thinking of simple examples such as evolution from north pole $|0\rangle$ to south pole under different Hamiltonians yielding possibly $|1\rangle$ or $i|1\rangle$). So, regardless the dimension of the state space - Bloch sphere or Bloch hypersphere - any Hamiltonian whose output differ by global phases are equivalent I guess suffices to me.

Comment: Yeah it's all good! But if something is still bothering you feel free to ask

Comment: @doublefelix I don't see that for an arbitrary  $|\psi\rangle$ with $U_1 |\psi\rangle = |\phi\rangle $ and $U_2 |\psi\rangle = e^{i\theta} |\phi\rangle$ (with $U_i$ the evolution operator associated to $H_i$) would imply that $H_1 =H_2+ C$. Could you elaborate? What I mean is that the relation given in the question does not hold for all states, but only for one, special state. For example, it could be that $H_1$ and $H_2$ have an eigenvector $|\psi\rangle$ in common, but all other properties would be different. Then I would not say that both Hamiltonians are 'equivalent' (whatever this means).

Comment: @Jakob I added a proof of this to the end of the answer.

Comment: The word equivalent here just means that at your convenience, you can add or subtract a real number from a Hamiltonian without changing experimental results. Just like in classical mechanics where the absolute energy doesn't matter, only differences in energy.

Comment: However the eigenvalues will of course change. So we are talking in the context of time evolution here, not in finding the eigenvalues to find the possible observable energies.

Comment: @doublefelix The point is that the relation must not hold for all $|\psi\rangle$; in the question and comments it is mentioned that the relation holds for a specific state! Additionally, in your penultimate equation you write $itH+i\theta = it(H+\theta)$.

Comment: I added the $t$ in, it was a slip-up. Thanks for pointing that out. As for OP's question I didn't see the clarification in the comments until writing my answer. His point that $H$ should not depend on the state in the comments of this answer made me think that my answer was appropriate to his question, but if it's not and he confirms it did not help I will add a disclaimer at the beginning or possibly delete the answer.

Comment: unless I'm misunderstanding something, this seems wrong. Even if you simplify this to ask equality on *all* input states with zero phase difference, *i.e.* $e^{iH_1}=e^{iH_2}$, it is very much possible that $H_1-H_2$ is not a constant (by which I assume you mean a multiple of the identity, for finite dimensional systems). As a trivial two-dimensional example, consider $H_1=2\pi I$ and $H_2=2\pi X$ with $X$ Pauli matrix

Comment: @glS Could it be that you misinterpreted what was being answered? I'm having a difficult time parsing your issue with the above. Which step exactly do you see fault in? Also, evolution by $H_1 = 2 \pi I$ does not produce the same as evolution by $H_2 = 2 \pi X$ on every possible state $\psi$ for all $t$. The $H_1$ in your example never evolves the state besides a phase and the $H_2$ clearly can (try it on any state besides an eigenstate of $X$).

Comment: @doublefelix I'm saying $e^{2\pi i I}=e^{2\pi i X}$, so yes, they act identically on every state. You can see it by simply computing the exponential. Of course, I mean for a fixed time $t$, which is what the question seems to be about. If you ask the entire dynamics generated by $H_1$ and $H_2$ to coincide then sure, the Hamiltonians need to be equal as well.

Comment: Taking OP's question "If two hamiltonians produce the same evolution up to a phase are they equivalent?" I interpreted this to mean that they produce the same evolution in general, rather than just at particular time(s) $t_i$. Thus I had assumed the statement to be for all $t$, which I did specify in my answer. This is the source of our disagreement. If my assumptions about OP's question are wrong I am open to be corrected by him.